# Allowing User to select Image from camera and Gallery dose not work for installed app like Camera360

Tags: android, image, camera

I'm newbie in Android development. Well my application allows the user to select images from a gallery and to captures image taken from camera. Well it works perfectly fine while picking an image from a gallery and Native Camera but it dose not work when picking an image from an installed app like Camera360. Can anyone help me with this issue.

Below is my code to show a options to select images from Gallery and camera

```
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Test" + File.separator);
    if (!root.exists())
        root.mkdirs();
    String fname = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    // Camera.
    List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }
    // Filesystem.
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");
    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

onActivityResult Method is implemeted below

```
          protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
            final boolean isCamera;
            if (data == null) {
                isCamera = true;
            } else {
                final String action = data.getAction();
                if (action == null) {
                    isCamera = false;
                } else
                    isCamera = action.equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
            Bitmap yourSelectedImage;
            if (isCamera) {

                yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outputFileUri.getPath());
            } else {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            }
            com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView CircularImageView = (com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
            CircularImageView.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
        }
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly fine for both camera and gallery image picker. But it crashes for installed app like Camera360. Can some one help me regarding this

Comment: "it crashes" that is very unhelpful. You must supply a stack trace and show which are the lines of code the stack trace mention.

Answer (score 1):

A `Uri` is not a file, and so you cannot pass it to `decodeFile()` on `BitmapFactory`. Your "pretend this `Uri` actually came from `MediaStore`" code will not work either.

Either use an image loading library like Picasso or Universal Image Loader, or have your own background thread that uses `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to read in the contents of that `Uri`, passing the stream to `decodeStream()` on `BitmapFactory`.

> The code works perfectly fine for both camera and gallery image picker.

Only for the couple of cases that you tried. For example, if the "gallery image picker" returns an image that is on removable storage on Android 4.4+, even if you *could* get a filesystem path, you can't read it, as you don't have read access for arbitrary locations on removable storage.

Comment: Well i'm basically trying to implement update profile picture just like a Whats up app. Can you please give me a reference as i m very new to android.

Comment: I have another question, will sockets and http work together in one application, use case is : I have chat running on sockets and other data pulled from server!! Please advice!!

Comment: @Nilesh: "Can you please give me a reference as i m very new to android" -- sorry, but I do not know what "a reference" means. "will sockets and http work together in one application" -- that should be fine, but it is not related to this answer. If you have additional unrelated questions, ask a fresh Stack Overflow question.